# What are the public transport options to the Hungaroring?

Tags: public-transport, tips-and-tricks, hungary, budapest

We'll be attending the Formula 1 race in Aug, 2020 at the Hungaroring. We'll be staying somewhere in Budapest (exact location yet to be determined, but likely near some of the touristy places).

What are the public transport options (2 quite able adults carrying small day-packs) to travel between (downtown-ish) Budapest and the track? Currently, according to Google maps, it's a 1.5-2.5 hour bus ride (from generic, downtown Budapest). However, it's showing the next departure time is 22:50. At this time of the evening, it makes sense that buses may not be running with the same frequency they would be on Friday through Sunday morning.

- Are there dedicated buses running to the track?
- Does the regular city bus line run to the track much more frequently during "normal" daytime hours making it a much shorter trip?
- Is there some sort of train/tram (that doesn't run this late in the evening)?
- Is there some other dedicated "to the track" transportation that could be recommended?
- I'm sure I could get a taxi, but since I'll be an obvious tourist and don't speak Hungarian, I'm not sure that I'd get a great deal...

I'm not opposed to renting a car and driving (did that for the Austrian GP last year) if driving is the best option (Google is showing <30 min drive time - I know it will be more with race traffic), but it seems that public transport would likely be a better, simpler option since the track is fairly close (22 km) to downtown.

*If someone has local knowledge of the Budapest area and/or has attended the Hungarian GP and has recommendations of a better place to stay than downtown, I'm certainly open to options, but that's really a secondary issue (and probably worthy of its own question, eventually), and that would be better suited to a comment rather than an answer. (No, track-side camping is **not** an option.)*

Comment: For an event of that size it's likely that the local bus companies will be running special services over the F1 weekend, but the information might not be published yet.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass I would think that you are correct. I'm hoping that someone local to Budapest or someone who has attended the race in the past would be able to chime in with some confirmation one way or the other.

Answer (score 3):

What I've found so far (most links are in Hungarian):

There's a [map](https://hungaroring.hu/hu/kapcsolat/megkozelites/volanbusz-jaratok) on the track's website that lists suggested directions. This is from 2016, but Volan's website (long-distance bus/coach company) [approves](https://www.volanbusz.hu/hu/menetrendek/vonal-lista) this, these bus lines still exist.

So you can use Volan's 321 line from Újpest Városkapu (also, station on the "blue" metro line M3). This uses M3 motorway. If you're afraid of congestion, you can use H8 HEV line from Örs Vezér Tere to Mogyoród, and use one of the other options backwards (320, 321, 325, 326), or simply walk. Szilasliget (also a H8 HEV station) could also be an option. Örs Vezér Tere can be reached by the "red" metro line M2. (just to know: normal HEV tickets and seasonal tickets are only valid within the city, when you leave the city borders you need to pay some extra)

Taxis are regulated, there's a 300HUF/km fixed price, and a 700HUF base price no matter which taxi you use, and their cars look more or less identical (taxi companies fought united against Uber, that was the agreement in the end). You can even use price calculators beforehand to estimate what certain rides will cost. (e.g. Budapest Taxi has an Android/iOS app with in-built calculator)

You can rent or use your own car as well. In this case be sure to have a vignette for Pest county.

If you're really loaded, there's a helicopter service between Budapest and Hungaroring in that period. They take off from the river banks. (at least earlier years this was the case)

> Are there dedicated buses running to the track? Does the regular city
>   bus line run to the track much more frequently during "normal" daytime
>   hours making it a much shorter trip?

I have no experience with F1 specifically, but other large events (kayaking, swimming, etc.), yes, this is the case.

> Is there some sort of train/tram (that doesn't run this late in the
>   evening)?

For me, Google Maps shows 1:02-1:28 long rides. You can set departure time, maybe that was your problem (Hungary uses CEST, so UTC+2 in August). In general, nighttime public transport is infrequent. There are night buses (the ones with 9xx numbers), and tram line 6. Night bus 992 goes there, but I don't suggest it.

Other suggestions:

If you arrive by plane, only exchange a small amount of money at the airport for your ride/ticket, even better, if you can get some at home. The money exchanger at the airport is a ripoff! Other [changers](https://correctchange.hu/en/exchange-rates/) tend to be all right.

It seems Hungaroring tickets are 15% off until the end of the year.

If you're from the EU, you can use your mobile internet here as well. That might come handy whichever travel option you choose. BKV/BKK has their own timetable app, but Budapesti Menetrend is also good for timetables. OTP's Simple app can be used to but vignette or pay for parking, and so on.

Oh, and of course in case of large events the timetables tend to change accordingly.

(I've never visited F1, but I live in Budapest.)

Comment: Great info, thank you! I'll have to take some time to parse all this...